# On changing layout Orientation application crashes?

Tags: android

When i Change the layout Orientation application crashes in the simulator??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"><View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View><TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp" android:background="@drawable/table_one">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <View android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></View></TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"><TextView android:gravity="center|left"android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="20" />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/Spinner01" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_weight="80"></Spinner>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="Status :" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/Spinner01" android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="70"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
        <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="30" android:text="Type :"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
        <TextView android:textColor="#250517"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
            android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="70" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/table_one" android:layout_height="90dp">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
        <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
        <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Document" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/btn_browse" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="80"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
<TableLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bsckround" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="160dp">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Print" android:id="@+id/btn_print"
            android:layout_width="106dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Settings" android:id="@+id/btn_setting"
            android:layout_width="106dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/btn_cncl"
            android:layout_width="106dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
```

Comment: what is the error from logcat?. Also, which android:orientation are you referring to? you have in base LinearLayout and TableLayout.

Comment: Base is a LineraLayout..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

```
<activity android:name=".ShareTweet" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

to make perfect code.

Comment: i think there is smting wrong with my layout..can you check that

Comment: Above code only help you for setting the screen orientation in portrait mode. This is constant,

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the screen, the activity is created again. 
Look in your onCreate() method for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*i hope this will help you. Add this with activity class in manifest file*

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```